# protractor : element stored in a variable is changing if the result of the locator change

Tags: protractor

I have a list of invitations and want to see if the first pending one has been accepted after some trigger.

```
<div class="invitation">
  <h1>A</h1>
  <div class="PENDING">PENDING</div>
</div>
<div class="invitation">
  <h1>B</h1>
  <div class="PENDING">PENDING</div>
</div>
```

some code inside specs to store first pending **invitation with h1 A**

```
// get first element with css .PENDING
let pendingTxt = element.all(by.css('.PENDING')).get(0);

// get its parent : div.invitation with h1 A
let invitation = pendingTxt.element(by.xpath('ancestor::div'))
```

Here some script update invitation to status ACCEPTED

```
<div class="invitation">
  <h1>A</h1>
  <div class="ACCEPTED">ACCEPTED</div>
</div>
<div class="invitation">
  <h1>B</h1>
  <div class="PENDING">PENDING</div>
</div>
```

But if I log invitation now it will return **invitation with h1 B**.

Which means that invitation has been updated according to pendingText locator. I'm not sure to understand why.

But i can't find way to properly store the original invitation. I tried to clone it with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `pendingTxt` holds a Promise for an `ElementFinder` which will locate an element every time it is resolved. You are not storing an element, by the mechanism to locate it.

So to store an element, you first have to resolve the Promise to a `WebElement`:

```js
protractor.promise.fulfilled(element.all(by.css('.PENDING')).get(0))
  .then(status => {

    expect(status.getText()).toEqual('PENDING');

    //  accept the invitation 

    expect(status.getText()).toEqual('ACCEPTED');

  })
```

Or to a list of web elements:

```js
element.all(by.css('.PENDING')).then(statuses => {

  expect(statuses[0].getText()).toEqual('PENDING');

  //  accept the invitation 

  expect(statuses[0].getText()).toEqual('ACCEPTED');

})
```

Comment: Thanks I understand, i should learn more about promise. But i'm a bit confused. looking at the doc http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get, it access getText() directly after the get(index). And trying your code i got the following error : element.all(...).get(...).then is not a function.

Comment: My bad the API doesn't provide a direct method to resolve an `ElementFinder`. See fixed update.